# What happens when Rails.cache.fetch expires

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, caching

I'm generating json of 65,000 users to populate a typeahead.  The query is quick, turns out building the json was the bottleneck.  I'm trying to cache the result but what happens when the cache expires, does it rebuild it automatically or is it going to wait until someone triggers the call, resulting in a 9-second page load once every 12-hours?

```
def user_json
  Rails.cache.fetch("users", expires_in: 12.hours) do
    User.all.to_json
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to hit the database each time then you could look in to a solution such as elastic search or sphinx which are designed to perform quick searching like your describing.

I was listening to javascript jabber this morning and they where saying that the average web page is now a shade under 2mb including images and CSS. Your request doubles that size. While that's fine for north Americans your page is likely to feel much slower in internet backwaters such as Australia.

It's also worth noting that older browsers such as IE don't handle iteration in javascript too well. I would suggest that your application would crash in any IE pre version 9.

Because of these reasons I would avoid pushing JSON that contains 65,000 rows over the wire and in to the browser. If the query is quick why not do a trip back to the server each time the user changes the input. Many trips back to the server based on input would be quicker than sending all 65,000 records and in the process removes the entire class of problems I have described above.  Your original problem also goes away as you don't have to cache any responses any more.

Comment: I see what you're saying, it's just that angular's fuzzy filter is blazing fast, even for 65k records.  The whole json object is only around 2mb, which is huge for an object but still - the filtering happens instantly.

Comment: Fair enough. I have expanded my answer to address some of these issues.